# convert nested dictionary into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

example dictionary:

```
sample_dict = {'doctor': {'docter_a': 26, 'docter_b': 40, 'docter_c': 42}, 
               'teacher': {'teacher_x': 21, 'teacher_y': 45, 'teacher_z': 33}}
```

output dataframe:

```
job     person     age
doctor |doctor_a | 26
doctor |doctor_b | 40
doctor |doctor_c | 42
teacher|teacher_x| 21
teacher|teacher_y| 45
teacher|teacher_z| 33
```

I have tried:

```
df = pd.dataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict)
```

=>

```
             doctor      teacher
doctor_a  |  26      |   Nah
doctor_b  |  40      |   Nah
doctor_c  |  42      |   Nah
teacher_x |  Nah     |   21
teacher_y |  Nah     |   45
teacher_z |  Nah     |   33
```

Could someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Is `dataFrame` a typo? It should be `DataFrame`, no? Same for `Nah` vs `NaN`.

Comment: `docter` is a typo, and it doesn't match between input and output

Comment: Related: [Nested dictionary to multiindex dataframe where dictionary keys are column labels](/q/24988131/4518341). If you use the solution in the accepted answer and transpose after, you get pretty much what you want, just need to reset index and rename.

Answer (score 4):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
pd.DataFrame([[k1, k2, v]
              for k1,d in sample_dict.items() 
              for k2,v in d.items()],
             columns=['job', 'person', 'age'])
```

Output:

```
       job     person  age
0   doctor   docter_a   26
1   doctor   docter_b   40
2   doctor   docter_c   42
3  teacher  teacher_x   21
4  teacher  teacher_y   45
5  teacher  teacher_z   33
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `zip` of length 3 elements, and feed them to `pd.DataFrame` after reshaping:

```
zip_list = [list(zip([key]*len(sample_dict['doctor']), 
                 sample_dict[key], 
                 sample_dict[key].values())) 
            for key in sample_dict.keys()]

col_len = len(sample_dict['doctor']) # or use any other valid key
output = pd.DataFrame(np.ravel(zip_list).reshape(col_len**2, col_len))
```